# Prevent unit tests but allow integration tests in Maven

Tags: maven, build, integration-testing, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

I've a Maven build in which I use the SureFire plugin to run some unit tests, and the FailSafe plugin to run some integration tests.  I would like a way to run just the FailSafe plugin's tests.

It's not a good solution for me to add different profiles or anything in the pom, because it's a multimodule build and I don't want to have to edit every module's pom.

There are `skip.tests` and `maven.test.skip` and `skipTests` which stop *all* tests, and [`skipITs`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/verify-mojo.html#skipITs), which stops only the failsafe plugin.

So, is there a command-line flag for Maven like `skipITs`, but instead with the functionality of "onlyITs"?

Comment: Did you try `maven.test.skip` or `skipTests`?

Comment: What is the exact reason to just run the integration test? Usually Unit tests are very fast so not a real problem?

Comment: @khmarbaise in theory, yes. But in most projects I have worked in, the "unit tests" where actually integration tests with an in-memory db (if you were lucky)

Comment: @khmarbaise Lots of unit tests.  They take a couple of minutes to run and we don't need them to run in this circumstance.  Specifically, we run unit tests before building the artifact (of course), but we want to run the ITs in multiple environments.  No point re-running the unit tests at this point.

Comment: If you have to run your integration test into different environments i would suggest to put the integration test into a separate Maven Module instead of combining that with Unit Tests. The problem is that Maven will run the unit tests usually in it's life cycle...? Other question: How many Unit tests do you have? (May you have to make the unit tests faster?)

Comment: Hi @khmarbaise, in my set up `skipTests` skips only the surefire tests, not the failsafe test! Maybe it's a new feature ?

Comment: FYI : skipTests is now deprecated in Failsafe Plugin 3.0.0-M3 ([SUREFIRE-1611](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1611))

Comment: Have Failsafe Plugin 3.0.0-M5 and it still skip integration tests with `skipTests`. According to the comment in source code `skipTests` will be removed in Failsafe 3.0.0

Comment: Trivial in modern technologies like Node. I hate Java!

Answer (score 208, accepted):

I found the simplest way to skip only surefire tests is to configure surefire (**but not failsafe**) as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.14</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- skips surefire tests without skipping failsafe tests.
                 Property value seems to magically default to false -->
        <skipTests>${skip.surefire.tests}</skipTests>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This allows you to run `mvn verify -Dskip.surefire.tests` and only surefire, not failsafe, tests will be skipped; it will also run all other necessary phases including pre-integration and post-integration, and will also run the `verify` goal which is required to actually **fail your maven build** if your integration tests fail.

Note that this redefines the property used to specify that tests should be skipped, so if you supply the canonical `-DskipTests=true`, surefire will ignore it but failsafe will respect it, which may be unexpected, especially if you have existing builds/users specifying that flag already. A simple workaround seems to be to default `skip.surefire.tests` to the value of `skipTests` in your `<properties>` section of the pom:

```
<properties>
    <skip.surefire.tests>${skipTests}</skip.surefire.tests>
</properties>
```

If you need to, you could provide an analagous parameter called `skip.failsafe.tests` for failsafe, however I haven't found it necessary - because unit tests usually run in an earlier phase, and if I want to run unit tests but not integration tests, I would run the `test` phase instead of the `verify` phase. Your experiences may vary!

These `skip.(surefire|failsafe).tests` properties should probably be integrated into surefire/failsafe code itself, but I'm not sure how much it would violate the "they're exactly the same plugin except for 1 tiny difference" ethos.

Comment: Using this solution I've been able to set up my framework so -DskipUnitTests skips over the surefire plugin, -DskipIntegrationTests skips over the failsafe plugin, and DskipTests skips over both.  Exactly what was needed!

Comment: my IDE is complaining about "cannot resolve symbol 'skipTests'"
the solution was to add a line `<skipTests>false</skipTests>`
still works with any combination of -DskipTests or -Dskip.surefire.tests as command line args seem to overwrite properties https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708738/how-to-get-a-command-line-property-to-overwrite-a-maven-property
you may want to add that to your solution

Comment: `<skipTests>${skip.surefire.tests}</skipTests>` is not working with `maven-surefire-plugin` version `3.0.0-M3`.  All the surefire tests are still running. Anyone else found this?  Sean Patrick Floyd's below solution is however working.

Comment: About "however I haven't found it necessary - I would run the test phase instead of the verify phase.", this would disable a test coverate analysis run by Jacoco in the "verify" phase, and u may want to see your Unit test coverage without integration tests.

Answer (score 133):

A workaround would be to call:

```
mvn clean test-compile failsafe:integration-test
```

Admittedly, this is ugly, but it may solve your problem.

---

Or (another hack):

```
mvn clean integration-test -Dtest=SomePatternThatDoesntMatchAnything -DfailIfNoTests=false
```

**Reference:**

- [`surefire:test#test`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#test)
- [`surefire:test#failIfNoTests`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#failIfNoTests)

Comment: Is this a good idea? **Won't this result in your build succeeding even if your integration tests fail?** That's the whole essence of failsafe, [if you don't *also* run the 'verify' goal](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/). Quote: "The Failsafe Plugin will not fail the build during the integration-test phase". You need run the verify goal to actually tell you whether the integration tests succeeded or not!

Comment: @bacar is right, but just use `verify` instead of `integration-test` in the 2nd solution.

Comment: @MatthewGilliard still a bit hacky, if you have no good reason to be setting `-DfailIfNoTests=false` anyway (failsafe will respect this flag too)... but I'm groping for flaws now :-)

Comment: If you add `failsafe:verify` to the end of the first hack (`mvn clean test-compile failsafe:integration-test failsafe:verify`) it will fail the build if one of the integration tests fails.

Comment: The first solution also works with running a single test: `mvn -Dit.test=<testName> failsafe:integration-test`

Comment: One reason to skip (huge piles of) unit tests and ignore verify is that one is debugging an integration test or a bug that it has uncovered.

Comment: `mvn clean test-compile failsafe:integration-test` is working with version `3.0.0-M3`.

Comment: A reasonable choice for `SomePatternThatDoesntMatchAnything` is this: `!*`, matching nothing.

Comment: this is not hacky at all -- I think the first suggestion is the "real", canonical answer -- it runs precisely the goals that you want it to run

Comment: For simply running just the integration tests, doing `mvn integration-test` doesn't work (it runs through the unit tests first), but your suggestion `mvn failsafe:integration-test` does the trick (ugly or not). Fabulous, for a 13-year-old answer!

Answer (score 116):

I am using the code from [Antonio Goncalves Blog](https://antoniogoncalves.org/2012/12/13/lets-turn-integration-tests-with-maven-to-a-first-class-citizen/) , which works perfect.

You can use the following properties:

`-DskipUTs=true` for skipping surefire tests.

`-DskipITs=true` for skipping failsafe tests.

`-DskipTests=true` for skipping all tests.

The `pom.xml` is as follows:

```
<properties>
    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
    <skipITs>${skipTests}</skipITs>
    <skipUTs>${skipTests}</skipUTs>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>${skipUTs}</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>run-integration-tests</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
                <skipITs>${skipITs}</skipITs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: thanks, great approach! it also useful to override default execution of surefire (default-test) see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935181/what-does-the-default-test-stand-for-in-the-maven-surefire-plugin

Comment: Really a nice solution. However, the failsafe configuration is redundant as `skipITs` is the default.

Comment: SkipITs is a custom option in this config. You right in the default implementation, but that was not the OPs question.

Comment: In my opinion this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 31):

Hope this helps!

Try to run test only with FailSafe (plugin for integration-test - it will allow you to run only integration tests with this kind naming, by default:
**/IT*.java, **/*IT.java, **/*ITCase.java; , but you can easily change that from pom file)

```
mvn failsafe:integration-test
```

And when you want to use only SureFire (plugin for unit-testing)

```
mvn surefire:test
```

or one test at a time with:

```
mvn -Dtest=MyUnitlTest
```

Comment: This should have more votes! Simple and works!

Comment: This works but disables other plugins who run only in the "verify" phase like test coverage analysis with Jacoco.

Answer (score 15):

I do like this so every phases are normally executed:

```
 mvn -Dtest=foo -DfailIfNoTests=false verify
```

Comment: doesn't require adding anything in the pom as the OP asked and runs all phases as indicated.  great answer.

Comment: This trick is underrated. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

This skips the `UnitTests` triggered by `SureFire` and tests only one test:

`mvn failsafe:integration-test -Dit.test=YourTestName`

You can also provide a pattern:
`mvn failsafe:integration-test -Dit.test=*`

(Maven 3.6.3)

Answer (score -2):

Try running your integration or unit tests in a separate profile. Then you can just enable/disable the profile.

Comment: Maybe add parent pom in which you define profile that is running only ITs? all project sub modules could inherit form that pom, so you wouldn't need to change every pom or run modules with special switches (as you can activate profile on property absence).