# Running two maven profiles

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pom.xml, maven-surefire-plugin

My profiles in `pom.xml`

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
            <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>test-output</directory>
                        <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>runWithHead</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.18.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>execution1</id>
                            <configuration>
                                <systemPropertyVariables>
                                    <homepage>${ADDRESS}</homepage>
                                    <head>true</head>
                                    <browsers>${browser}</browsers>
                                    <chromeDriverLocation>${chromeDriver}</chromeDriverLocation>
                                </systemPropertyVariables>
                                <suiteXmlFiles>
                                    <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                                </suiteXmlFiles>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>runHeadlessly</id>
        <properties>
            <displayProps>target/selenium/display.properties</displayProps>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>xvfb</id>
                            <phase>test-compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>xvfb</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <browsers>${browser}</browsers>
                                <displayPropertiesFile>${displayProps}</displayPropertiesFile>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.18.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>execution2</id>                 
                            <configuration>
                                <systemPropertyVariables>
                                    <homepage>${ADDRESS}</homepage>
                                    <head>false</head>
                                    <display.props>${displayProps}</display.props>
                                    <browsers>${browser}</browsers>
                                    <chromeDriverLocation>${chromeDriver}</chromeDriverLocation>
                                </systemPropertyVariables>
                                <suiteXmlFiles>
                                    <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                                </suiteXmlFiles>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

So first we have got shared plugins and then two different profiles. 
When i try to run them with one command

```
mvn clean install -P runHeadlessly,runWithHead
```

Only plugin with `xvfb` id gets executed, any ideas?
(did not post the part with default property variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined two profiles:

- First profile, `runWithHead`, defines an execution of the `maven-surefire-plugin` **without specifying any goal** element (within a [`goals`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.5/maven-model/maven.html#class_execution) section), hence an empty execution
- Second profile, `runHeadlessly`, defines an execution and goal of the `selenium-maven-plugin` plugin AND again an empty execution of the `maven-surefire-plugin`

As such, both profiles are executed, but effectively only the `xvfb` of the `xvfb` execution of the `selenium-maven-plugin` would be performed.

Since the `maven-surefire-plugin` has only [one goal](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/), [`test`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html), try to add the following to both executions:

```
<goals>
   <goal>test</goal>
<goals>
```

---

Also note: you are configuring additional executions of the `maven-surefire-plugin` on top of the default `default-test` execution which will also be executed. Hence, enabling both profiles you will end up with **three** executions of this plugin.

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by "default default-test execution which will also be executed" ?

Comment: by default the `maven-surefire-plugin` has already a [default binding](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.2/maven-core/default-bindings.html) to the `test` phase, that is, you type `mvn test` (or `mvn install`) and the surefire plugin will already be executed by default, the magic is in the default bindings (see previous link). here you are adding further executions rather than configuring the default one. I just wanted to point it out (or let you know). This is not necessarely bad practice, it depends on your requirements actually.

Comment: Well I guess I need to find out how to configure plugins with default bindings, so that I get 2 executions.

Comment: In this case you can override the configuration of the default execution by simply reusing the same execution id, hence replace `execution1` by `default-test` would be fine. check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935181/what-does-the-default-test-stand-for-in-the-maven-surefire-plugin) for instance: you can even skip the default execution and keep your executions for clarity.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips, hopefully someone else will also find them useful like I did.