# how to execute only integration test in spring boot using maven

Tags: maven, spring-boot, junit4, maven-failsafe-plugin

I am trying to separate unit and integration tests through maven command.

pom.xml

```
....

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Fast*</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is my integration test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = StudentApplication.class,
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class StudentControllerIT {

...
```

and this is unit test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = StudentController.class, secure = false)
public class StudentFastControllerTest {

....
```

Now when I try to run command `mvn test` then only  `StudentFastControllerTest` tests are executed but when I run command `mvn integration-test` or `mvn verify` both test classes are executed instead of only `StudentControllerIT`.

Comment: Check this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612344/prevent-unit-tests-in-maven-but-allow-integration-tests

Answer (score 5):

Edit: There are two approaches that worked for me:

1) using maven-failsafe configurations (I got help from to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60555919/4828060)):

```
   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>it-tests</id>
                <phase>none</phase> 
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Note that this execution is i) identified by the word **it-tests** and ii) has its phase set to **none**. The latter detaches these tests from the default lifecycle whereas the former enables us to run them on demand using the following command:

```
mvn failsafe:integration-test@it-tests
```

It is also important to have the integration tests suffixed with `IT` and the same way we include them in this `<includes>` section we do the same to the `<exclude>` sections of the other plugins such as surefire.

---

2) using profiles

In the **profiles section** you add a profile for your integration tests:

```
            <profile>
            <id>it-tests</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

Additionally, add the following to the profile configuration section **if** you have you integration tests in a separate test source directory, in this case `test-integration`:

```
<testSourceDirectory>test/test-integration/java</testSourceDirectory>
```

Now go back to the **plugins section** and on your `maven-surefire-plugin`, exclude the integration tests from `mvn test` by adding the following to its configuration section:

```
<excludes>
    <exclude>**/*IT.java</exclude>
</excludes>
```

Finally, add the following executions to your maven-failsafe-plugin:

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>integration-test</goal>
            <goal>verify</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

As a result (at least in my case), the integration tests are not executed during `mvn test` but when I run:

```
mvn failsafe:integration-test -Pit-tests
```

only my integration tests get executed.

I hope this works for you too.