# Maven failsafe is not complaining that an inexistent profile was specified

Tags: maven, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have two profiles in my pom:

```
 <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>functional-tests</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <testSourceDirectory>test/test-functional/java</testSourceDirectory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*FT.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>it-tests</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <testSourceDirectory>test/test-it/java</testSourceDirectory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        ...
```

I can trigger each of these two profiles like this:

```
 mvn failsafe:integration-test -Pfunctional-tests

 mvn failsafe:integration-test -Pit-tests
```

But when I run this:

```
 mvn failsafe:integration-test -PrandomWord
```

It triggers `it-tests` profile. I was wondering why and if there is a way to have failsafe plugin output something like unrecognised profile.

Thank you for your help

---

In case it matters, here is my failsafe-plugin:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: if you call a goal of a plugin `:integration-test` or something similar you don't start a life cycle. I recommend to start a life cycle like `mvn verify -P...` instead ...cause you also have defined a goal `verify` of maven-failsafe-plugin which is bound to verify cycle which will not called...furthermore the include configuration using `*IT.java` is the default in maven-failsafe-plugin

Comment: I removed the verify goal. I do not want these sets of tests to be part of the life cycle - instead I want to run them separately and on demand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your question about why it triggers `it-tests`. In fact, it does not activate any of the profiles, hence default plugin configuration is used which has `**/*IT.java` in include list. So, it runs all `IT` tests by default.

This is weird approach to manage plugin executions by profiles. I doubt there is a reasonable way to validate profile names as you describe. I would recommend another approach here.

### Approach 1. Use `<id>` and cli with @

You could just specify two executions of the plugin with `id` and then you could do this: [How to execute maven plugin execution directly from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166538/how-to-execute-maven-plugin-execution-directly-from-command-line)

```
 <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>it-tests</id>
            <phase>none</phase> <!-- detach this execution from default lifecycle -->
            <configuration>
                <testSourceDirectory>test/test-it/java</testSourceDirectory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>functional-tests</id>
            <phase>none</phase> <!-- detach this execution from default lifecycle -->
            <configuration>
                <testSourceDirectory>test/test-ft/java</testSourceDirectory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*FT.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Now you could execute it from command line:

```
mvn failsafe:integration-test@it-tests
mvn failsafe:integration-test@functional-tests
```

**Update**: No need to specify `goals` as it is relevant to lifecycle only, we type it in command line anyway.

### Approach 2. Use `<skip>` and properties

Keep both executions as a part of lifecycle but control execution by providing skip flags. I.e. define two properties e.g. `skip.tests.it=true`, `skip.tests.ft=true` and add `<skip>${skip.tests.ft}</skip>` to relevant configuration sections. Then you could just do

```
# run with no tests by default
mvn verify 

# run with only FT
mvn verify -Dskip.tests.ft=false 

# run with all tests
mvn verify -Dskip.tests.ft=false -Dskip.tests.it=false
```

to run full lifecycle together with desired tests.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Perhaps I should have given a little more context. I am using profiles because I want to exclude all IT and FT from maven default lifecycle, i.e. I want to run IT and FT in a separate maven goal and on demand.

Comment: @JoãoMatos You missed my comment in the snippet how to _detach this execution from default lifecycle_ using `<phase>none</phase>`. I've done it for FT only, but you could do it for both.