# How to skip integration tests by default but still run them on-demand in multi-module maven project?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have a multi module project having the following structure:

```
Project:    
 - module1
 - module2
 - integration-test
 - parent pom
```

What is the correct way of achieving the following:

- run unit tests from all modules(except integration-test) using `mvn clean install`
- run integration tests on demand(may be by using maven-failsafe plugin or via a maven profile? )
- fail the build when integration tests fail.
- By Default integration tests should not be run using `mvn clean install`
- integration-test module has only the integration tests.

I have tried multiple hacks using maven-failsafe plugin and maven-sunfire-plugin(for unit tests) but not able to achieve the above in standard way.

Following is how the relevant portion of integration-test pom looks like:

```
<dependencies>
   <!-- dependencies required for this module-->

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-integration-test-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>src/test/java</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-integration-test-resources</id>
                    <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin> 
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>run-its</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

currently when i run `mvn clean install` it runs integration tests too. When i run `mvn -Prun-its clean verify`, it is running unit tests from other modules too. what am i missing?

Comment: If you like to run integration tests only on demand the best is to make a profile inside the integration-test module called for example `run-its`...

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612344/prevent-unit-tests-but-allow-integration-tests-in-maven?rq=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can skip execution of the Integration tests simply by setting `-DskipITs=true` when running your build like so:

```
mvn clean install -DskipITs=true
```

this will run all other tests but your ITs (see [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/verify-mojo.html) for doc).

If you only want to run

```
mvn clean install
```

you can set the default for skipITs in your pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <skipITs>true</skipITs>
</properties>
```

This way you can override it on demand with

```
mvn clean install -DskipITs=false
```

To run only ITs without Unittests you can configure the -Property of the `maven-surefire-plugin` like so

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <skip>${skipUnitTests}</skip>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

so if you run

```
mvn clean install -DskipITs=false -DskipUnitTests=true
```

Note that `skipUnitTests` will be `false` by default so no need to declare a property for that.

If you'd rather use a Profile it should work like that

```
    <profile>
        <id>ITs</id>
        <properties>
            <skipUnitTests>true</skipUnitTests>
            <skipITs>false</skipITs> 
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

and run the build like so

```
mvn clean install -PITs
```

Of course you could also use the plugin-configuration for `maven-surefire-plugin` with true directly in the profile so there'd be no need for the extra property, like

```
<profile>
    <id>ITs</id>
    <properties>
        <skipITs>false</skipITs> 
    </properties>
    <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
                <configuration>
                   <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
       </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Comment: Better handling the IT's in a separate module which contains a profile to activate the running of IT's...

Comment: @khmarbaise: Could you please post an example of what you are suggesting. i see your point made on the previous ans as well and agree to it as well. but may be i m missing something in my implementation.

Comment: @tom: i want to achieve the following:    
`mvn clean install` - run all unit tests except integration tests    
`mvn clean verify` OR mvn clean install -Pit - run only integration tests and nothing else.

Comment: Ok,  but my answer works for your first requirement? (skip its when running mvn clean install)

Comment: yes it works for the first requirement. i am looking to achieve both in my setup.

Comment: Updated the answer, should now also cover your second requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that's the best solution but you can achieve that using profiles. For example in the main pom.xml you add just the other modules in the `<modules>` section and then add another profile:

```
<modules>
... standard modules ...
</modules>
<profiles>
 <profile>
   <id>tests</id>
      <modules>
        <module>module1</module> 
... standard modules repeated (it might not be needed>...
        <module>module2</module>
        <module>module-integration-test</module>
      </modules> 
  </profile> 
</profiles>
```

Then you run maven with that profile if you wnat to run tests.

```
maven -P tests clean install
```

That would work if you want to run integration tests AND the other modules. If you want to run just the integration tests you can do it like that:

```
<modules>
  <!-- EMPTY -->
</modules>
<profiles>
 <profile>
   <id>defaultModule</id>
   <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
   </activation>
     <modules>
        <module>module1</module> 
... standard modules repeated (it might not be needed>...
        <module>module2</module>           
      </modules> 
 </profile>
 <profile>
   <id>tests</id>
      <modules>           
        <module>module-integration-test</module>
      </modules> 
  </profile> 
</profiles>
```

This way with mvn clean install you will run with defaultModule (which is activeByDefault) and if you specify -P tests you will run just tests

Comment: i tried the following but it runs other modules' unit tests too. i tried with both adding all modules in the profile section and also with keeping only integration-test module. but it did not work as expected. it is running all the unit tests too.

Comment: ah I thought you want to include the tests. If you want to run just the tests you can add another profile for everything else. One profile for all modules, another profile for integration tests and empty <modules> section. But you will also have to include a profile ;) I will edit my answer

Comment: Using profiles for modules is a very bad idea cause it will cause issues which are hard to identify better make the profile inside the module (see http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2013/11/09/why-is-it-bad-to-activate-slash-deactive-modules-by-profiles-in-maven/)

Comment: Ah never thought about that with the versions :) Good call

Answer (score 0):

The best is to make a separate module which contains the integration tests which looks like already shown in your own question. Now how to handle the integration tests being running or not ...

The integration-test module looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>groupOfYourParant</groupId>
    <artifactId>integration-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>integration-test</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Mod-IT</name>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>groupId</groupId>
      <artifactId>TheArtifact</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Supplemental deps only needed in this module -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>....</groupId>
      <artifactId>....</artifactId>
      <version>...</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>run-its</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

By using this you can simply control to run the integration tests via:

```
mvn -Prun-its clean verify
```

It's important that you have define the dependencies to other modules which are needed by the integration tests module or where it made be sure that those modules have to be built before this integration test module.

Furthermore you can now configure here supplemental things which are needed for integration tests and which should be run for example in the `pre-integration-test` and/or in `post-integration-test` phase.

If you put the test code into `src/test/java` plus optional resources into `src/test/resources` you can now define dependencies within your integration test module separately from any other module.

You should of course define the versions for your plugins in a pluginManagement in your parent pom to define all plugins which are being used during a build.

Comment: i tried the above approach and unfortunately, this too does not work as expected :(. running `mvn clean install` runs all tests. which is not what i want. running `mvn -Prun-its clean verify` runs all tests of other modules as well which is again i dont want to happen. May be i am missing something. i am updating my question with the setup of my `integration-test` module.