# Add two flags in Maven tag to SkipTests

Tags: java, scala, maven, maven-failsafe-plugin

I´m using a ScalaTest plugin to execute some IT test.  I need to skip all the test(`Unit, IT`) in some pipelines, and they only use the flag `${skipTests}` so I need to use that flag for all my types of testing. In local sometimes I want just to execute, unit or IT test, but now having only one flag it´s not possible.

Only comment the line in the plugin of the IT it would works but I dont like this error prone aproach(Someone will commit the comment line for sure)

```
                <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
```

I was thinking that it would be great if I can use some sort of `OR` condition to set a new flag in my local executions as true and keep the other as false

```
            <skipTests>${skipTests} || ${skipItTests}</skipTests>
```

Obviously this is not working, but I was wondering if someone know a way to do what I want.

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been already answered in [Prevent unit tests but allow integration tests in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612344/prevent-unit-tests-but-allow-integration-tests-in-maven)

At glance you can use following pom snippet for being able running any combination of (UNIT, IT) tests.

```
<project>
  ...
  <properties>
    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
    <skipITs>${skipTests}</skipITs>
    <skipUTs>${skipTests}</skipUTs>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version> <!-- use appropriate version -->
        <configuration>
          <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
          <skipITs>${skipITs}</skipITs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version> <!-- use appropriate version -->
        <configuration>
          <skipTests>${skipUTs}</skipTests>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

And use

- `mvn install -DskipUTs` : Skips Unit tests
- `mvn install -DskipITs` : Skips Integration tests
- `mvn install -DskipTests` : Skips both Unit and Integration Tests

Original post is https://antoniogoncalves.org/2012/12/13/lets-turn-integration-tests-with-maven-to-a-first-class-citizen/

Comment: Thanks a lot I will use this aproach

Comment: Please use up-to-date versions of the plugins not that old ones...The versions can be found here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/